# How to effectively split numeric column into groups with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a numeric column and try to use the `case_when` function. I know that `ntile()` can split numerics into equal groups, like

```
# data
data = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), time=seq(1:3), x=seq(from=10, to=120, by=10))

# automatic grouping works
data%>%
  mutate(x_group = ntile(x, n=4))
```

but I'm would like to specify these groups by hand:

```
# manual grouping fails 
data %>%
  mutate(x_group = case_when(x < 30 ~ 1,
                               30 <= x < 50 ~ 2,
                               50 <= x < 70 ~ 3,
                               70 <= x ~ 4))
```

I guess the problem might be in the combination of the conditionals?

Comment: Another alternative might be `?cut` - which saves you having to make sure you match each of the start and end points of groups - `data %>% mutate(x_group = cut(x, c(-Inf,30,50,70,Inf), right=FALSE, labels=FALSE))` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify two separate logical comparisons in R

```
data %>%
  mutate(x_group = case_when(x < 30 ~ 1,
                             30 <= x & x < 50 ~ 2,
                             50 <= x & x < 70 ~ 3,
                             70 <= x ~ 4))
```